# Form header:location sequence order

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Hi I'm trying to redirect to the next page after data is sumbmitted to mysql. I have so far

```
<?php
$name = "";
$email = "";
$msg_to_user = "";
if ($_POST['name'] != "") {
    include_once "newsletter/connect_to_mysql.php";

    // Be sure to filter this data to deter SQL injection, filter before querying database
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM newsletter WHERE email='$email'");
    $numRows = mysql_num_rows($sql);

    if (!$email) {
      $msg_to_user = '<br /><br /><span style="font color="FF0000">Please type an email address ' . $name . '.</span>';

    } else if ($numRows > 0) {
      $msg_to_user = '<br /><br /><font color="FF0000">' . $email . ' is already in the system.</font>';

    } else {    
      $sql_insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO newsletter (name, email, dateTime) 
        VALUES('$name','$email',now() )")  or die (mysql_error());
      $msg_to_user = '<br /><br /><div style="color=#F47926;">Thanks ' . $name . ', Now lets select what you need.</div>';
      $name = "";
      $email = "";
    }
    header("Location: order.php");
}
?>
```

This sends the data to my database and everything works great, but I'd like to  send it to another page at order.php thats already created to continue. The form I've got right now is here

```
<form style="border:0;padding-left:10px;" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
  <fieldset style="text-align:left;" id="free"> 
  <span style="text-align:left;font-size:30px;color:#F47926;">
    Ready to get started?
  </span>
  <div class="centerForm">
    Name:<br />
    <input name="name" type="text" maxlength="36" size="35" value="" /><br /> 
    Email:<br />
    <input name="email" type="text" maxlength="36" size="35" value="" /><br />
    <br /><br /><div style="width:179px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;"><input type="image" src="continue-to-selection.png" name="mySubmitBtn" alt="continue to selection" /></div>                        
  </fieldset> 
</form>
```

The email function worked before, but it stopped working as I began changes. This I'm sure is something simple and I'm sure I can work it out. My issue is that I'm trying to re-direct after submission of data to mysql, the user to a page order.php. Are the changes that I need to make supposed to be within the form or through the header:location I'm trying to use. Thanks
Note: I shortened urls to view it within the post preview here so I'm aware that the order.php must be full path. Correct me if I'm wrong, but just letting you all know I am aware and this was not the issue.

Comment: You never send a message. Then you redirect to order. Are you expecting order to maintain the variables set on the first page? Have you looked into $_SESSION to store temporary values?

Comment: Hi Kai I havn't begun that part just yet. My only concern right now is getting to the page order.php after mysql submission of name and email. Outside of that I can do without any message ect.

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 approches that I would suggest you try.
1st one (personally prefered) is to use ajax and jquery to submit the form and then display the thank you message without refreshing the page. After that use settimeout function to delay the redirect for x seconds and then redirect to the order page.

2nd approche: is after the data get saved in the database store a success message in a session. then in the header of the order page, use an if statement based on the session. if it's success or true then show the message the thank you message in the order page.

If you want to see an example of the solutions provided, let me know.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good rule - Avoid echoing HTML from php. Close the script tag write your HTML and continue your PHP

Also @vidit is right.
try this

```
else {    
      $sql_insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO newsletter (name, email, dateTime) 
        VALUES('$name','$email',now() )")  or die (mysql_error());
      $msg_to_user = '<br /><br /><div style="color=#F47926;">Thanks ' . $name . ', Now   
      lets select what you need.</div>';
      //$name = "";
      //$email = "";
      session_start();
      $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
      $_SESSION['email']=$email;
    }
```

and in the next file you can get the email and name back using

```
session_start();
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$name= $_SESSION['name'];
```

Also look into PDO as an alternative if you are using PHP>5.1

Also, it wouldnt hurt to add some session handling which you can learn 
here

Cheers!

Comment: I'm totaly confused now....I'm still having the same issue of getting to order.php once I've submitted the form. Your takling about transferring the message to the next page right? the session. Lets eliminate any message so I can regain an understading. I just want the data to be stored then taken to the order.php. I think thats my main issue. I think I may be able to wrok out the sesssion, but getting to that order.php is the issue.

Comment: @HireLogo : Is the page not redirecting at all or is it throwing some kind of error ?

Also try removing the **or die()** part of your code and echo the output to see if the query is executing with some error. Sometimes the insert will happen but there will be an error nonetheless.

**EDIT** Also, you could try to use PDO which has its own error handling mechanism. That plus you can trust it to be sql injection safe for the most part.